# I need to modify my jquery scroll-to-anchor code so it will scroll to an achnor on a new page as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery I have a snippet of code that works great to smooth scroll to a page anchor. But I need to make this work from another page as well. Is there anything I can do to the code below?

Example: From pg 1, click on a link to an anchor half way down page 2. I wanted the browser to jump to the top of page 2 and then scroll down to the anchor. I cant figure out how to do that with this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
                $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
                    var $anchor = $(this);               
                    $('html, body').stop().animate({
                        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                    }, 2400,'easeInOutExpo');

                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });


            $(document).scroll(function(){
        t = (100 - $(this).scrollTop())/100;
        if(t<0)t=0;
        $('.skyB').css({opacity: t})
    })

</script>
```

Revised code does not seem to work either

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      var id = location.hash; // includes the leading #
      $('ul.nav a[href$="'+id+'"]').click();

            $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
                var $anchor = $(this);               
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                }, 2400,'easeInOutExpo');

                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });


        $(document).scroll(function(){
    t = (100 - $(this).scrollTop())/100;
    if(t<0)t=0;
    $('.skyB').css({opacity: t})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract the hash ID with `location.hash` and re-use your event handler.

```
$(function() {
    var id = location.hash; // includes the leading #
    $('ul.nav a[href$="'+id+'"]').click();
    // continue as before
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I must be doing something wrong because that didn't seem to work either: see revised posted code. Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.